# Two plug-in power mics and a y adapter

Tags: microphone, zoom, plugin, plug-in

Is it ok to connect two plug-in power mics using a Y adapter to a single mic jack?

Specifically, to a Zoom H5.

*Edit*

I have been using two battery powered mics for a year going through a y adapter and into a mic jack, and never had a problem.

But now I have two plug-in power mics and I'm wondering if they are going to do any damage to the device. I have tested it briefly and the recording works perfectly. I'm just concerned about doing damage.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to Phantom Power (+48V) yes you could drive two off a single jack but you should NOT be connecting two microphones to a single input. This will cause problems when you go to record. Inputs (on recorders) are generally designed to see a single device, if you want to use 2 mics you will need two inputs.

If you post an edit of what it is your trying to accomplish we may better be able to offer some advice.

- Edit -
  I would not think it would do any damage. Generally speaking the jacks on devices have limited power driving functionality (enough to drive one mic). I would think that you would experience poor performance long before anything broke. On top of that most decent makers put overload protection and other various things into the circuitry now to protect the more fragile parts.

Comment: added details to question

Comment: Thanks for the update. Just so you know, I get the same quality recording whether using one plug-in mic or two with the y-adapter.